# Real estate schema markup not showing up on Rich Results test

Tags: plugins, php, themes, tags, theme-customizer

I am not very techy, but I am trying to add schema markup to real estate listings automatically. The site is built using MyHome theme.

Here is an example of a listing that I want to add schema markup to https://westlands-consult.co.ke/property/house/kaya-diani-fully-furnished-4-5-bedroom-beachfront-houses-for-sale-in-diani-mombasa/

Below is the PHP code that I added to the site but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Kindly assist

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'myhome_real_estate_listing_schema' );
function myhome_real_estate_listing_schema() {
    // Get the post ID
    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    // Check if the post is a real estate listing
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) !== '$myhome_estate' ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the listing data
    $title = get_the_title( $post_id );
    $description = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'description', true );
    $price = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'price', true );
    $bedrooms = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'bedrooms', true );
    $bathrooms = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'bathrooms', true );
    $property_type = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'property_type', true );
    $address = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'address', true );
    $image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id, 'full' );

    // Build the schema markup
    $schema = array(
        '@context' => 'https://schema.org',
        '@type' => 'RealEstateListing',
        'name' => $title,
        'description' => $description,
        'price' => $price,
        'numberOfRooms' => $bedrooms,
        'numberOfBathrooms' => $bathrooms,
        'propertyType' => $property_type,
        'address' => array(
            '@type' => 'PostalAddress',
            'streetAddress' => $address,
        ),
        'image' => $image,
    );

    // Echo the schema markup
    echo '<script type="application/ld+json">' . wp_json_encode( $schema ) . '</script>';
}
```

Comment: I suspect the line `if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) !== '$myhome_estate' )` should be `if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) !== 'myhome_estate' )` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly, RealEstateListing is not supported by Google, so you couldn't see the results in Rich Results Test.